# Failed to automate the release of space in SQL Server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to automate the process of releasing the space of the databases in a SQL server, for this I assembled the following script with 3 particular cases (according to the business rules of the institution). The first is the `tempdb`, I separate this database because I cannot apply the`alter ... recovery` (I do not know if it is necessary to apply the release of space to this database). The second rule is for a particular database `BD_MAIN`, which has four data files and four log files, I only apply for the last two files. The third case is by discarding, for all the remaining databases.

```
            EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
            '
                use [?]

                declare 
                @arch_1 sysname,
                @arch_2 sysname,
                @bd_name sysname

                set @bd_name=(select DB_NAME())
                set @arch_1 =(select name FROM SYSFILES
                              where fileid = ''1'')
                set @arch_2 =(select name FROM SYSFILES
                              where fileid = ''2'')

                -- 1st case: If the data base is tempdb:
                if (@bd_name=''tempdb'')
                begin
                    select name from sysfiles

                    DBCC SHRINKFILE (tempdev, 1)
                    DBCC SHRINKFILE (templog, 1)
                end

                -- 2nd case: If the data base is BD_MAIN:
                else
                begin
                    if (@bd_name=''BD_MAIN'')
                    begin
                        select name from sysfiles

                        DBCC SHRINKFILE (BD_MAIN4 , 1);

                        ALTER DATABASE BD_MAIN
                        SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
                            DBCC SHRINKFILE (BD_MAIN_log4 , 1);
                        ALTER DATABASE BD_MAIN
                        SET RECOVERY FULL
                    end

                    -- 3rd case: Another data bases:
                    else
                    begin
                        select name from sysfiles

                        DBCC SHRINKFILE (@arch_1 , 1)

                        ALTER DATABASE [?]
                        SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
                            DBCC SHRINKFILE (@arch_2 , 1)
                        ALTER DATABASE [?]
                        SET RECOVERY FULL
                    end
                end
            '
```

The problem that I have with this script is when I am in ´tempdb´, it is supposed that I should not enter the last `else` (for other cases), however it throws me the following error message (4th line):

```
DBCC execution completed. If there are error messages, consult your system administrator.
DBCC execution completed. If there are error messages, consult your system administrator.
Mens. 5058, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
The 'RECOVERY' option can not be set in the 'tempdb' database.
DBCC execution completed. If there are error messages, consult your system administrator.
You can not reduce the file '2' in the database 'model' to 128 pages, since it only contains 96 pages.
DBCC execution completed. If there are error messages, consult your system administrator.
DBCC execution completed. If there are error messages, consult your system administrator.
DBCC execution completed. If there are error messages, consult your system administrator.
DBCC execution completed. If there are error messages, consult your system administrator.
```

I would like to know if the code can be improved to avoid this kind of error messages since I want to incorporate it into a stored procedure or some recommendation about the release of space (how, when and when to do it).

Comment: Stop automating the shrinking of things; it is an utterly useless exercise. If the database has grown once, it will grow again, so what purpose did *temporarily* making it smaller serve? Did you lease the space out *also temporarily*? Please read: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/1186 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/44889/1186

Comment: It is actually worse than useless because of the huge amount of fragmentation is introduces. If you don't also rebuild all of your indexes this type of script only accomplishes slowing down your entire database.

Comment: You see, in my organization, the main database is "hit" for a week (monthly) by 3 processes of massive load of records, what has happened is the constant fall of these processes for not foresee the increase in the size of these during and after the processes and therefore what has been done so far is to release all the databases belonging to the hard disk that was left without space in order to reach the available size that the process required. What you are looking for is to automate this process.

Comment: Additionally, I also commented that there is a weekly full backup schedule and one of the daily log, these are made outside of office hours (that is, when there is no transaction) this schedule varies slightly from another database to another. Another detail according to the link that was provided to me is that the databases have the default configuration of growth in both files.